# Bootstrap Side Navbar fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having this code and want it to be always visible even when scrolling down:

```
 .sidenav {
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 100%;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .sidenav {
                height: auto;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .row.content {height:auto;} 
        }
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
        .row.content {height: 450px}

        body { padding-top: 45px; }

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
                <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
                <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
                <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
            </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kuukdn9u/

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not clear. What do you want to be visible when scrolling down ? If your talking of your nav bar, it's already fixed.

Comment: set css value - position: fixed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like both sides bar to be visible:

Apply ad ids named `sidenav-left` and  `sidenav-right` to sidebars on left and right respectively. This will allow on these two elements to be affected by new styling.

Position these elements using `fixed`

Push the div containing the text in the middle or away form the left sidebar to prevent overlapping when position fixed is applied to the sidebar on the left

You may use these rules below

```
.text-center {
  left: 150px;
}

#sidenav-left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  left: 0
}

#sidenav-right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

[see codepen here](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/NpBBqO)